# How to parallelize several apache spark rdds?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the next code:

```
sc.parquetFile("some large parquet file with bc").registerTempTable("bcs")
sc.parquetFile("some large parquet file with imps").registerTempTable("imps")
val bcs = sc.sql("select * from bcs")
val imps = sc.sql("select * from imps")
```

I want to do:

```
bcs.map(x => wrapBC(x)).collect
imps.map(x => wrapIMP(x)).collect
```

but when I do this, it's running not async. I can to do it with Future, like that:

```
val bcsFuture = Future { bcs.map(x => wrapBC(x)).collect }
val impsFuture = Future { imps.map(x => wrapIMP(x)).collect }
val result = for {
  bcs <- bcsFuture
  imps <- impsFuture
} yield (bcs, imps)
Await.result(result, Duration.Inf) //this return (Array[Bc], Array[Imp])
```

I want to do this without Future, how can I do it?

Comment: could you explain some more about what you do with wrapBC() or wrapIMP() and what you achieve with Future ?

Comment: @hnahak with wrapBC and wrapIMP I represent sql.Row to BC and IMP objects. When I use Future, bcs.map(x => wrapBC(x)).collect and imps.map(x => wrapIMP(x)).collect are running asynchronously on spark, otherwise sequentially.

Comment: Is your goal to speed up the computation, or something else? `map` is already parallelizable - why do you want to run the two `map` calls in parallel?

Comment: @stholzm Yes, it is.  If I use Future, then this code works nearly 20% faster.

Comment: @stholzm I have two large parquet files: bc and imp.

Comment: @Leonard Is the result of both calls really Unit? Can you show us more code? It may be beneficial to build a longer chain of transformations instead of just `collect`ing eagerly. Might give Spark more room for optimizations.

Comment: @stholzm I have added more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `union` for solve this problem. For example:

```
bcs.map(x => wrapBC(x).asInstanceOf[Any])
imps.map(x => wrapIMP(x).asInstanceOf[Any])

val result = (bcs union imps).collect()
val bcsResult = result collect { case bc: Bc => bc }
val impsResult = result collect { case imp: Imp => imp }
```

If you want to use sortBy or another operations, you can use inheritance of trait or main class.

Answer (score 2):

**Update** This was originally composed before the question was updated.  Given those updates, I agree with [@stholzm's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29789042/2636793) to use `cartesian` in this case.

---

There do exist a limited number of actions which will produce a `FutureAction[A]` for an `RDD[A]` and be executed in the background.  These are available on the [AsyncRDDActions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.rdd.AsyncRDDActions) class, and so long as you import `SparkContext._` any `RDD` will can be implicitly converted to an `AysnchRDDAction` as needed.  For your specific code example that would be:

```
bcs.map(x => wrapBC(x)).collectAsync
imps.map(x => wrapIMP(x)).collectAsync
```

In additionally to evaluating the DAG up to action in the background, the `FutureAction` produced has the `cancel` method to attempt to end processing early.

### Caveat

*This may not do what you think it does.*  If the intent is to get data from both sources and then combine them you're more likely to want to join or group the RDDs instead.  For that you can look at the functions available in [PairRDDFunctions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions), again available on RDDs through implicit conversion.

If the intention isn't to have the data graphs interact then so far in my experience then running batches concurrently might only serve to slow down both, though that may be a consequence of how the cluster is configured.   If the resource manager is set up to give each execution stage a monopoly on the cluster in FIFO order (the default in standalone and YARN modes, I believe; I'm not sure about Mesos) then each of the asynchronous collects will contend with each other for that monopoly, run their tasks, then contend again for the next execution stage.

Compare this to using a `Future` to wrap blocking calls to downstream services or database, for example, where either the resources in question are completely separate or generally have enough resource capacity to handle multiple requests in parallel without contention.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** I misunderstood the question. The desired result is not the cartesian product `Array[(Bc, Imp)]`.

But I'd argue that it does not matter how long the single `map` calls take because as soon as you add other transformations, Spark tries to combine them in an efficient way. As long as you only chain *transformations* on RDDs, nothing happens on the data. When you finally apply an *action* then the execution engine will figure out a way to produce the requested data.

So my advice would be to not think so much about the intermediate steps and avoid `collect` as much as possible because it will fetch all the data to the driver program.

---

It seems you are building a cartesian product yourself. Try `cartesian` instead:

```
val bc = bcs.map(x => wrapBC(x))
val imp = imps.map(x => wrapIMP(x))
val result = bc.cartesian(imp).collect
```

Note that `collect` is called on the final RDD and no longer on intermediate results.

Comment: cartesian returns Array[(Bc, Imp)], what if I add another one RDD, like that: bc.cartesian(imp).cartesian(another).collect. It will return me Array[(Bc, Imp), Another)]. However, cartesian works very slow in this case, because bc might contain thousand rows, but imp might contain over million rows. What do you think?

Comment: `cartesian` actually returns RDDs on which you can chain other transformations before calling an action like `collect`. In your case, you may want to `filter` before `collect`. Or have a look at [PairRDDFunctions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions) @hayden.sikh mentioned, maybe there is a transformation closer to what you are trying to achieve. The idea is to build a chain of RDD transformations and only collect the end result.

Comment: @Leonard: it is still not quite clear to me what your goal is. The cartesian product of two large datasets is obviously an expensive operation no matter what. Think about why you need it. Maybe only to then JOIN the two tables? There are specialized RDD transformation functions that may serve you better.

Comment: my goal is get array of all Bc and array of all Imp. If I use `cartesian` it works about 2.2 minutes, but if i use `Future` it works about 1.1 minutes.

Comment: it does not matter, if we are talking about avoid `collect`. Because if I use `val bcs = sc.sql("select * from bcs where id = 1")` and `val imps = sc.sql("select * from imps where id = 1")` and then use `collect` for both, it also be very slow if I don't use `Future`. What do you think?

Comment: Add.. Yes, we must avoid collect as much as possible. But in this case it's whatever, because all filters use in sql query.